# std::enable_if with sfinae detection of a non-member existance

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I'm trying to detect the existance of a non-member function (global). In the following code the detection works fine, when the etest function is not defined with the expected signature both tests return 0 and they return 1 when it is defined. (You can check commenting/uncommenting the function "int etest(double)" )

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//
//uncomment the following and output will change to 1
//

//int etest(double)
//{
//    return 0;
//}

//sfinae test begin

struct Qu_Fake_Return{};

template <typename... Args>
Qu_Fake_Return etest(Args...)
{
    return {};
}


template<typename T>
struct exists_etest {
};
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct exists_etest< Ret(Args...)> {
    static constexpr auto test() ->
      typename std::is_same<Ret, decltype(etest(std::declval<Args>()...))>::type { return {}; }
    static constexpr bool value = test();
};
//sfinae test end

constexpr bool constTest()
{
    auto val=exists_etest<int(double)>::value;
    return val;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"exists constTest "<<constTest()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"exists "<<exists_etest<int(double)>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is using that detection mechanism (or maybe other) in order to make a template available. But using the sfinae detection with enable_if refuses to compile when the expected signature for etest is not defined.

The following fails to compile with the following error:
failed requirement 'exists_etest<int (double)>::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

```
//int etest(double)
//{
//    return 0;
//}

//sfinae test begin
...

template<typename N,typename std::enable_if<exists_etest<int(double)>::value,bool>::type=0>
void testTemplate(N a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}

...
```

The following compiles without problems:

```
int etest(double)
{
    return 0;
}

//sfinae test begin
...

template<typename N,typename std::enable_if<exists_etest<int(double)>::value,bool>::type=0>
void testTemplate(N a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}

...
```

Any ideas on how to enable a template based on the existance of a non-member function ?

Comment: `std::enable_if<exists_etest<int(double)>::value, bool>` doesn't depend on your template argument, which means there is no SFINAE.

Comment: Man ... so obvious ... thank's a lot, I'll close the question with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class A, class B>
struct second{using type=B;};
template<class A, class B>
using second_t=typename second<A,B>::type;

template<typename N,typename std::enable_if<exists_etest<int(second_t<N,double>)>::value,bool>::type=0>
void testTemplate(N a)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the mistake is to consider this SFINAE

```
template<typename N,typename std::enable_if<exists_etest<int(double)>::value,bool>::type=0>
void testTemplate(N a);
```

It is not, as none of the template arguments are used in the std::enable_if expression. One way to solve that is pointed out in Yakk-Adam's answer, but I think most of the time the template will use at least one argument coincident with the test, in that case SFINAE will resolve. ie:

```
template<typename N,typename std::enable_if<exists_etest<N(double)>::value,bool>::type=0>
void testTemplate(N a);
```